# VBA Email Problems

Tags: vba, excel, email

I am trying to setup the Email VBA to Read the info from specific cell references. I know i can put in the worksheet names and it will work that way but i need the file to be able to be very adjustable. This will be used across all our sites and they all vary quiet alot so i need to be able to make the file adjustable by anyone.

The code needs to read the info in worksheet 'Tracker' cell 'C6' and if it matches the number then copy multiple sheets into the temp file that is created to be emailed.

The range to be copied is C8:K8

I currently have the blow code:

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub Email()
        Dim FileExtStr As String
        Dim FileFormatNum As Long
        Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
        Dim Destwb As Workbook
        Dim TempFilePath As String
        Dim TempFileName As String
        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Dim TheActiveWindow As Window
        Dim TempWindow As Window
        Dim SendTo As String
        Dim SendCC As String
        Dim SendBCC As String
        Dim SendBody As String
        Dim Subject As String

    'Revert Main Sheet Name
    If Not ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Tracker").Range("B7").Value Then
    ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Tracker").Range("B7").Value
    End If
    'Main Code
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim Answer As String
    Answer = InputBoxDK("What's the password?", "Password")
        If Answer = Sheets("Passwords").Range("D8").Value Then
    'Stop Updating Screen
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        If Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("L7").Value).Range("D6") > 0 Then
        SendTo = Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("L7").Value).Range("D6")
        End If
            If Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("L7").Value).Range("D9") > 0 Then
            SendCC = Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("L7").Value).Range("D9")
            End If
                If Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("L7").Value).Range("D12") > 0 Then
                SendBCC = Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("L7").Value).Range("D12")
                End If
                    If Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("L7").Value).Range("H5") > 0 Then
                    SendBody = Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("L7").Value).Range("H5")
                    End If
                        If Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("L7").Value).Range("D17") > 0 Then
                        Subject = Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("L7").Value).Range("D17")
                        End If

        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .EnableEvents = False
        End With

        'Checks Range to see if they have values - email whatever has value
    If Sheets("Tracker").Range("C8").Value > 0 Then
    Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("C8").Value).Visible = True
        If Sheets("Tracker").Range("D8").Value > 0 Then
        Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("D8").Value).Visible = True
            If Sheets("Tracker").Range("E8").Value > 0 Then
            Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("E8").Value).Visible = True
                If Sheets("Tracker").Range("F8").Value > 0 Then
                Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("F8").Value).Visible = True
                    If Sheets("Tracker").Range("G8").Value > 0 Then
                    Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("G8").Value).Visible = True
                        If Sheets("Tracker").Range("H8").Value > 0 Then
                        Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("H8").Value).Visible = True
                            If Sheets("Tracker").Range("I8").Value > 0 Then
                            Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("I8").Value).Visible = True
                                If Sheets("Tracker").Range("J8").Value > 0 Then
                                Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("K8").Value).Visible = True
                                    If Sheets("Tracker").Range("K8").Value > 0 Then
                                    Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("K8").Value).Visible = True
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If


        Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

        'Copy the sheets to a new workbook
        With Sourcewb
            Set TheActiveWindow = ActiveWindow
            Set TempWindow = .NewWindow


'THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP    
    If Sheets("Tracker").Range("C6").Value = 9 Then
    Else: GoTo Skip1
    Skip1:
        If Sheets("Tracker").Range("C6").Value = 8 Then
        Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("C8").Value).Copy
        Else: GoTo Skip2
    Skip2:
            If Sheets("Tracker").Range("C6").Value = 7 Then
            Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("C8" & "D8").Value).Copy
            End If
        End If
    End If


        End With

        'Close temporary Window
        TempWindow.Close

        Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

        'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
        With Destwb
            If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
                FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
            Else
                Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
                Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                Case 52:
                    If .HasVBProject Then
                        FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                    Else
                        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                    End If
                Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
                Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
                End Select
            End If
        End With

        'Save the new workbook/Mail it/Delete it
        TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
        TempFileName = Sourcewb.Name & " " & Format(Now, "Mmmm")

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With Destwb
            .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = SendTo
                .CC = SendCC
                .BCC = SendBCC
                .Subject = Subject
                .Body = SendBody
                .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
                .Display
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            .Close savechanges:=False
        End With

            'Delete data to create template for next month

            '''''''''''''''''''''Sheets("Helmet1").Range("I8:P1008").Value = ""


        Else: MsgBox "Wrong password", vbCritical + vbOKCancel, "Incorrect Password"
        GoTo Exit1
        End If

        'Delete the file you have send
        Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing

       '''''''''''''''''''' Sheets("Main Page").Visible = True
       ''''''''''''''''' Sheets("Climbing Equipment").Visible = False
       ''''''''''''' Sheets("Helmet1").Visible = False

        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
    Exit1:
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Creating a new Window just opens another window on to the same workbook - it doesn't create a new Workbook object. Workbooks.Add is probably what you are looking for

Answer (score -1):

This is not a “do this and everything will be all right” answer because I am not sure what you are trying to do.  Instead it lists all the things I believe are mistakes which I hope will get you closer to the code you seek.

You appear to have two workbooks.  One contains the macro and the source data while the other is to be created by the macro, filled with selected data and then emailed. To handle this you have two workbook variables: `Sourcewb` and `Destwb`.  Both these variables are set to the `ActiveWorkbook`.

The following is probably correct:

```
Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook
```

although I prefer:

```
Set Sourcewb = ThisWorkbook
```

`ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook active when the user started the macro or which the macro has activated.  `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook containing the macro.

For example, suppose the user opens workbooks Xxx and Yyy and then from Xxx runs a macro in Yyy.  Xxx is the `ActiveWorkbook` and Yyy is `ThisWorkbook`.  You may think your users would never run a macro from another workbook but I have seen it done.

If Destwb is supposed to be a new empty workbook, the statement you want is:

```
Set Destwb = Workbooks.Add
```

This creates a new default workbook and sets `Destwb` to it.  By “default workbook”, I mean whatever Excel creates for you if you request a new workbook.  For me that is a workbook with three empty worksheets named “Sheet1”, “Sheet2” and “Sheet3”.  Your default workbook may be different; for example “Sheet” may be replaced by the word in the local language meaning “Sheet”.

Try this:

- Create a new workbook from the keyboard.  For me that workbook will be named “Book1” so “Book1” appears in the taskbar.
- Open the Visual Basic Editor and copy the following code to a new module.
- Run macro `Test1`.

.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test1()

  Dim Destwb As Workbook

  Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Name
  Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Name

  Set Destwb = Workbooks.Add

  Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Name
  Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Name

End Sub
```

On my system the following appears in the Immediate Window:

```
Book1
Book1
Book1
Book2
```

When the first two `Debug.Print` statements execute, there is only one open workbook and both `ThisWorkbook` and `ActiveWorkbook` reference it.  For the second two `Debug.Print` statements there are two open workbooks.  `ThisWorkbook` is unchanged but `ActiveWorkbook` now references the new workbook.

---

You want to load the controlling parameters from the source workbook so each site can have its own version.  This is an excellent method of having the same code do different things for different users.  However, you have made your code as difficult to understand as possible.  Consider:

```
If Not ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Tracker").Range("B7").Value Then
    ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Tracker").Range("B7").Value
End If
```

I deduce that cell B7 of worksheet “Tracker” contains the name of the worksheet containing the parameters.  However, you are using this to rename the active worksheet.  Is this what you meant?  I would have thought the following more appropriate.

```
Dim ParamsWs As Worksheet

Set ParamsWs = Worksheets("Tracker").Range("B7").Value
```

I would also copy the password to a variable:

```
Dim Password As String

Password = Worksheets("Passwords").Range("D8").Value
```

I have used `Worksheets` rather than `Sheets`.  This is me being pedantic; I prefer to be explicit which type of sheet I am referencing.   Since `Worksheets("Passwords").Range("D8").Value` is only accessed once, copying its value to a variable does save anything but I think it makes the code a little clearer.  Accessing a worksheet is slower than accessing a variable so you do not want to access the same cell twice.  More importantly, it is very unclear what these cells contain.  You may know at the moment but what about when you need to update this macro in six or twelve months?  What if someone else has to update this macro?  Why are you making it so difficult to understand what you are doing?

Consider:

```
If Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("L7").Value).Range("D6") > 0 Then
  SendTo = Sheets(Sheets("Tracker").Range("L7").Value).Range("D6")
End If
```

This can be simplified to:

```
With ParamsWs
  If .Range("D6").Value > 0 Then
    SendTo =.Range("D6").Value
  End If
End With
```

Notice that I have kept the period in front of `Range("D6").Value`.  Without the period, this references the active worksheet.  With the period, this references the worksheet specified by the `With` statement.

This cell contains a string so you should not be comparing it with zero.  The following would be correct:

```
  If .Range("D6").Value <> "" Then
    SendTo =.Range("D6").Value
  End If
```

However, the `If` serves no purpose.  If the cell contains `""`, that is the required value for `SendTo`.  This block can be replaced by:

```
With ParamsWs
  SendTo =.Range("D6").Value
  SendCC =.Range("D9").Value
  SendBCC =.Range("D12").Value
  SendBody =.Range("H5").Value
  Subject =.Range("D17").Value
End With
```

Note I have added `.Value` at the end of each assignment.  Again this is me being pedantic.  `Value` is the default property of a range and may be omitted but think the code is clearer if the property is always specified.

The heavily nested `If` statements appear to be setting any specified worksheets visible.  Is this necessary?  Is it likely they will be hidden?  Since the `If` statements are nested, one blank cell and the rest are not checked. Is this correct?  If it is correct, is it important?  Would the following be acceptable?

```
Dim CellCrnt As Range

With ParamsWs
  For Each CellCrnt In .Range("C8:K8")
    If CellCrnt.Value <> "" Then
      Worksheets(CellCrnt.Value).Visible = True
    End If
  Next
End With
```

This code would check every cell in the range even if an earlier one was blank.  I have used a `For Each` statement which adds a little complexity but I believe the smaller block of code compensates.  Also the `For Each` statement should be part of the armoury of any VBA programmer.

I believe the code playing with Windows is a complete misunderstanding.  My guess is you want to copy the worksheets specified in .Range("C8:K8") to the new workbook.  This is not done with Windows.

Please explain what you are trying to do and I will try to help.

**Edit** Part 2

The macro below does what I think you want.  It creates an empty workbook, copies selected worksheets to it and saves it ready to be emailed.  But, first a few points.

---

I have not copied worksheets recently and did remember the exact syntax.  Searching for “Excel VBA Copy worksheet to another workbook” brought up a page which showed me what to do.  If you can break your requirement down into single steps like this, you can usually find the help you need.

---

If I write:

```
Dim X As Long
```

then X can hold a number in the range –2,147,483,648 and +2,147,483,647.

If I then write:

```
X = "abc"
```

I will get a “Type Match” error.  Properly typing your variables can be a real help with avoiding assignment errors. However, sometimes you need a variable that is not restricted to a single type.  I can write:

```
Dim X As Variant

X = "abc"
X = 5
X = True
```

With this code, X will in turn hold a string, an integer and a Boolean.  I cannot imagine a use for this functionality but the following is very useful.

```
Dim X As Variant

X = Range("A1").Value
X = Range("A1:F1").Value
X = Range("A1:A20").Value
X = Range("A1:F20").Value
```

For the first statement, I do not know what sort of value cell A1 contains but it does not matter, X will hold it.

In the other statements, I load part of a row, part of a column and a rectangle; that is I load several values that may be of different types.  In each case X will be holding a two dimensional array with the first dimension holding rows and the second dimension holding columns.

This has two advantages. (1) Copying a large block of cells to a Variant and then accessing the values within the Variant can be substantially faster than accessing the values individually from the worksheet.  (2) Accessing several worksheets in the same block of code can get complicated.  Copying data to a Variant can simplify the code.

I have loaded Range("C8:K8") to a Variant for advantage 2.

---

If I am correct this code demonstrates the functionality you seek.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateNewWorkbook()

  Dim ColWtcCrnt As Long
  Dim WbkDestName As String
  Dim WshtCrnt As Worksheet
  Dim WshtCrntName As Variant
  Dim WshtParam As Worksheet
  Dim WshtToCopy As Variant
  Dim WbkDest As Workbook
  Dim WbkThis As Workbook

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set WbkThis = ThisWorkbook

  Set WshtParam = Worksheets(WbkThis.Worksheets("Tracker").Range("B7").Value)

  ' Load range into a variant as a 2D array
  WshtToCopy = WshtParam.Range("C8:K8")

  Set WbkDest = Workbooks.Add

  With WbkDest

    For ColWtcCrnt = 1 To UBound(WshtToCopy, 2)
      WshtCrntName = WshtToCopy(1, ColWtcCrnt)
      If WshtCrntName <> "" Then
        Set WshtCrnt = WbkThis.Worksheets(WshtCrntName)
        WshtCrnt.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        WbkThis.Worksheets(WshtCrntName).Copy after:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
        WshtCrnt.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
      Else
        ' This assumes all the names are on the left of the range
        Exit For
      End If
    Next

    ' Delete default worksheets
    For Each WshtCrnt In .Worksheets
      If Left$(WshtCrnt.Name, 5) = "Sheet" Then
        ' Delete worksheet without displaying confirmation dialog box
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        WshtCrnt.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
      Else
        ' New sheets were added on right so default sheets are on the left
        Exit For
      End If
    Next

  End With

  ' Don't worry about the extension. Let Excel decide which is best.
  WbkDestName = Format(Now(), "yymmdd hhmmss")

  WbkDest.SaveAs (WbkThis.Path & "\" & WbkDestName)
  WbkDest.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tony, Thanks for the assistance. As mentioned before i am very new to this and self taught so all help is much appreciated.

Comment: Ok. for a break down of the file. The file will run similar to a website. Sadly the hiding of sheets is an absolute must as people seem to have the power to destroy only that which they can see. With the sheets hidden they are unable to 'accidentally' delete an entire Sheet as excel wont allow it. They are also not able to unhide anything, Very Hidden, so they dont miraculously come across the hidden objects.

Comment: I realize my code i currently have is very messy and will need a lot of tiding up. I appreciate your help and explaining of the "." before range. That will be very useful in the very near future as much as it has been today. The file however is a massive spiderweb really. The Sheets you were referring to with the ParamsWs would need to be where all the email info is collected. SendTo, BCC, etc. However, the range of where the cells are that need to be checked for names of sheets to copy lies in a different sheet again.

Comment: A lot of this has been done so as people will be able to edit the file to quite an extent without ever having TRUE access to the file. Even with the passwords they have and can alter throughout the file, they are very limited in what they can do in terms of destruction. Even had to cancel copy and paste...

Comment: At the moment the 1 big piece i am missing is the code to copy multiple sheets that are determined by a set range. Cant seem to get that to work. Other than that i am jsut about sorted with this part of the file.

Comment: Hi Tony, tried the code you gave me. Not what i need. It seems to hide the tabs i want and the file it creates has everything inside range C8:K8.

Comment: Hi Tony. thanks again but didn't work as expected. The part of the code i currently need is to simply copy the range i have set. C8:K8 - i know the code you gave me now hides the files in those cells. But the 'New' file it creates is nowhere to be found. and it includes all other Tabs aswell. The main reason i need only the selected tabs to be copied is to bring down the size of the file to be emailed. This file will contain 4 Areas each with 9 Sub Areas. The Sub areas are emailed together as per the Area. Difficult to explain the entire system with writing.

Comment: Would it be possible for me send the file to you so you have a better understanding of what i need to do. The file is completely blank so no company information will be included. As mentioned before, I am very new to this. I can make it very simple to understand if I am able to show you the file but seem to struggle when doing so in typing as i can visualize it in front of me but you cannot as I'm pretty sure i have confused you to hell and back at this point.

Comment: I created a workbook with six very hidden worksheets plus worksheet "Tracker" and one named "Xyz" containing the range C8:K8. The range C8:K8 contains the names of three of the very hidden worksheets. My **tested** macro: gets "Xyz" from "Tracker" then the names from the range, creates a default workbook, copies the worksheets named in the range to the new workbook, deletes the default worksheets and saves the new workbook in the same folder as the orginal workbook under a name based on the current date and time in the format "yymmdd hhmmss". ...

Comment: ... This may not do what you want but it does do what I thought you wanted. There is an email address within my StackExchange profile but I am not sure how seeing your workbook would help me understand what you want.

Comment: The range C8:K8 is inside worksheet "Tracker". The one named "XYZ" is where the email info would be pulled from. (SendTo, SendBCC, etc.). Your tested macro is then exactly what I am looking for just need to set the 2 different parameters for each sheet. I tried doing that with the code you sent me but was then stuck with the email not working.

Comment: I am sorry I got confused about the location of range C8:K8. Are you saying you have got as far as creating the workbook but cannot email it successfully?

Comment: Yes that about sums it up nicely.

Comment: @MichaelduToit  If you search for "excel vba send email outlook" you will find several pages offering help.

Comment: Thanks for all the assistance. Will take a serious look at tiding my code up and making it easier to read. Starting out so doing the effort of writing out everything as long as possible and will adjust and compress fro there. Just need to get it to work first before i worry with anything else. Thanks for the insight and the explanations, just goes to show how much i still need to learn.